# Extract first set of records in JSON C#

Tags: c#, json, xml

I have a requirement to get the first set of records in c# JSON. Here is my JSON data for example

```
string sJSON = "{
    { 
        "ID": "1", 
        "Name":"John", 
        "Area": "Java" , 
        "ID": "2",
        "Name": "Matt",
        "Area": "Oracle" , 
        "ID": "3","Name": 
        "Danny","Area": "Android"
    }
 }"
```

I need to extract only the 1st set of records (i.e. `{{"ID": "1", "Name":"John", "Area": "Java"}}`).

If there is only one record my code (see below) works fine but when there are multiple records it takes the last set of JSON data (i.e. `{{"ID": "3","Name": "Danny","Area": "Android"}}`).

```
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(sJSON);
string sID = (string)jsonObject["ID"];
string sName = (string)jsonObject["Name"];
string sArea = (string)jsonObject["Area"];
```

Can anyone help me extract only the 1st set of JSON data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return the JSON data as JSON Array, now it is a simple JSON string.

If you're able to generate like below then you can easily get the single JSON element easily.

```
[{ "ID": "1", "Name":"John", "Area": "Java" },{ "ID": "2","Name": "Matt","Area": "Oracle" },{ "ID": "3","Name": "Danny","Area": "Android" }  ]
```

Use the below link, to understand this JSON format. 
http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: I am using an array [] Code - JArray a = JArray.Parse(sJSON); Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Parse the data as JToken. 
Such that you have something like:

```
var jToken = JToken.Parse(sJSON);
var isEnumerable = jToken.IsEnumerable()  

if(isEnumeable)
{
cast as JArray and get firstOrdefault
}                 

var isObject = jToken.IsObject();
if(isObject )
{
cast as JObject and perform straight casting
}
```